# Can't unquote play.api.libs.json.JsObject, consider providing an implicit instance of Liftable[play.api.libs.json.JsObject]

Tags: scala, scala-macros, play-json

I try to generate a JsObject with Scala macros.
The return type of my macros must be JsObject, but i can't.
It works with basic types (String, Int...)

```
object JsonSchema {


  def jsonSchema[T]: JsObject = macro impl[T]

  def impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context): c.Expr[JsObject] = {
    import c.universe._
    c.Expr[JsObject](q"""${play.api.libs.json.Json.obj("hello"->"world")}""")
  }
```

But i got the errror

`Can't unquote play.api.libs.json.JsObject, consider providing an implicit instance of Liftable[play.api.libs.json.JsObject]`

And i don't find good examples to make my own Liftable.

Comment: did you have try `reify(play.api.libs.json.Json.obj("hello"->"world"))`

Answer (score 1):

It works with :

```
implicit val l: c.universe.Liftable[JsObject] = Liftable((in: JsObject) => q"play.api.libs.json.Json.parse(${in.toString()})")
```

But I do not see the interest of this implicit